# $\int_{\{x:f(x)>k\}}f(x)dx=c$

Tags: probability, integration, algebra-precalculus, roots, self-learning

How is to find the value of $k$ for the following equation?

$$\int_{\{x:f(x)>k\}}f(x)\,dx=c,$$

where $c$ is a constant. Can anyone please show me a toy example from which I can understand how is to obtain the value of $k$?

Comment: It seems unlikely to find closed form for $k$ unless we know a closed form for the integral $\int f(x)\,dx$ .  Perhaps the problem is to show that such $k$ exists (without evaluating it)?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is a hard problem. Consider the graph below:

[image]

You're essentially asking to find the height of the horizontal line that makes the blue area equal to a given amount. Doing so will typically require:

- Showing that the integral converges;
- Finding a closed form for the integral;
- Being able to invert that closed form to solve for $k$.

*None* of these are guaranteed for a general function. If you at least have convergence then you can use numeric methods to find an approximation, but even then it's likely to be difficult.